# LR test for proportion of constants.

Tags: probability, statistics

$X_1,...,X_n$ are nonnegative r.v. with hazard function $\lambda(x)= \left\{ \begin{array}{}
\lambda_1 , x\leq x_0 \\
\lambda_2 , x>x_0 \end{array} \right.$

With $H_0:\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_2}=r$ versus $H_1:\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_2}\neq r$, with $r>0$.

I have to find the LR test for $H_0$ vs $H_1$.

So, The densities are $x\leq x_0: \lambda(x)=\lambda_1e^{-\lambda_1x}$, for $x> x_0$: $\lambda(x)=\lambda_2e^{-\lambda_2x}$. Is this correct?

Then I'm not sure, it seems that $ \displaystyle \sup_{\lambda_1,\lambda_2}f(x)=\left(\frac{n}{\sum^nx_i}\right)^ne^{-n}$, since, MLE for $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are equal to $\frac{n}{\sum^nx_i}$.

When I do $\displaystyle \frac{\sup_{\lambda_1,\lambda_2}f(x)}{\sup_{\lambda_1=\lambda_2r}f(x)}$ it seems to be always equal to 1.

Where did I do the mistakes?

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:I forgot to tell you, but I also post this question on https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/110324/lr-test-for-proportion-of-unknown-constants/110328#110328

So, if you post the answer on mathematics, would be kind enough to also post it on stats? This way I will not waste anybody's time. Many thanks.

Comment: And would you PLEASE stop posting all your questions here AND on stats.stackexchange? You're wasting everyones time.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I'll link them both to avoid wasting everone's time. Thanks for the warning. ;)

Comment: Next time you should choose to post your question on the site you think is the most suitable. If the question goes unanswered for a longer period, then you might want to post the question on the other site while mentioning that the question has already been posted. That's the way to go, at least in my opinion.

Comment: @StefanHansen +1. I'm in still in a learning phase concerning posting. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The density is certainly not what you write. Note that the survival function $S(x)=P(X_i>x)$ is given by
$$
S(x)=\exp\Big(-\int_0^x \lambda(s)\,\mathrm ds\Big)
=
\begin{cases}
\exp(-\lambda_1x),\quad &x\leq x_0,\\
\exp(-\lambda_1x_0-\lambda_2(x-x_0)),\quad &x>x_0,
\end{cases}
$$
and hence the density $f(x)=\lambda(x)S(x)$ is not of the form you write.

Comment: Many thanks for the insight Stefan. It helps a lot. ;)

Comment: I've tried solving the exercise, but still haven't managed to. I've just posted my problem on another question. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/885442/lr-test-on-proportion-of-constants-part-ii